# Python beautiful soup select text in attrs

Tags: python, html

The following is an example of the HTML code I want to parse:

```
<td style="padding-left:5px;" title="col1 : val1
 col2 : val2">
```

There are several rows.
I am using beautiful soup to parse the HTML code by selecting 'td' as follows

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

tbody=table.select_one('tbody')
tds = tbody.find_all("td")
```

In this example, How can extract col1=val1, col2=val2 as dataframe?
It is hard to me, because the values is in attrs.

```
col1   col2
==========
val1   val2
val1-2 val2-2
.
.
.
```

I try this

```
tds.attrs['title']
```

but my code is not working.

Give me hint..

Comment: Did you try `tds['title']`

Comment: And, note that you have used `find_all`, try selecting a single element and use `tds['title']`

Comment: Thanks! It works. But still I don't know how to the other rows. I can just get first data.

Comment: Are the column names same for every ```<td>``` ?

Comment: ```<tr><td style=~, title=~> </tr> ```
it is repeated ``

Comment: I mean ```col1``` and ```col2```, Are they same in all the ```<td>```?

Comment: Yes! same for every <td>

Comment: Since you have provided a single line of HTML, it is difficult to come up with a general solution. Could you share the URL, so that I can see if there is some other way to get data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Based on the data you have provided**, I have used `re` to separate out the `title` value, put them in a `dict` and converted it to a dataframe.

I have added an extra `<td>` to simulate getting data from all the `<td>`.

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = '''<td style="padding-left:5px;" title="col1 : val1 col2 : val2">Data1</td>
 <td style="padding-left:5px;" title="col1 : val3 col2 : val4">Data2</td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
tds = soup.find_all('td')
d = {'col1': [], 'col2': []}
for i in tds:
    title = i['title'].strip()
    f = re.findall(r'col1\s:\s(.*)\scol2\s:\s(.*?)$',title)[0]
    d['col1'].append(f[0])
    d['col2'].append(f[1])
    
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
```

```
   col1  col2
0  val1  val2
1  val3  val4
```